# How to update Intel graphics for a laptop whose manufacturer has stopped updating

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I have seen a lot of questions on this site asking about updating ATI and Nvidia graphics for laptops, with some very good solutions for them, however I have not seen any questions/answers for people only have Intel integrated graphics.

I have a HP Pavilion dv4-1465dx laptop, [according to HP](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=2100&lc=en&cc=ca&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3979340#N200) the latest Intel graphics available for a "Mobile Intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family" is version `7.15.10.1554 D` from 6/19/2009, however [according to Intel](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=Mobile%20Intel%C2%AE%204%20Series%20Express%20Chipset%20Family&ProdId=2991&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39) the latest for the same faimily is `8.15.10.2555` released on 10/19/2011.

Is there any way to use tweaked or replacement drivers with Intel like you can with ATI and Nvidia?

I am running Windows Visa x64.

---

I forgot to mention (as I figured anyone who has tried updating laptop drivers would have already know) the drivers by Intel will not install and tell me to go to my PC's manufacturer to get the latest drivers.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with Intel!

FYI, Intel makes graphics chips just like NVidia and ATI do. So the best place to get the latest video drivers for your Intel graphics adapter would probably be with Intel. Not with HP.

Don't get confused since Intel *also* makes various north-bridge/south-bridge chipsets which also require proper driver support. That's different!

Your embedded graphics adapter appears to be a "Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 4500MHD" when I checked with HP. So when checking with Intel it appear that the latest is version 15.17.18.2555 and available at the following URL:

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&keyword=%22Intel+Graphics+Media+Accelerator+4500MHD%22

That was released 10/19/2011. You might also like to know that it's not that critical to have the latest and greatest video drivers unless you're doing something intense like gaming in high resolution or video editing or something like that. Your laptop was obviously not built for video intense activities and simply watching videos is not really all that intense. So if you're updating drivers due to a video playback problem then be prepared that your drivers are not likely the cause. More likely would be your video driver configuration or some other factor such as codecs, fragmented HDD, etc. - not the fact that you don't have the latest drivers.

Comment: I know, that is the driver I referenced in my original post (see the number in the parenthesis next to the version number you quoted, then check the link in my question that goes to Intel's page and scroll to the Windows Vista/7 section), however when you try to install the driver it gives you a error message. See the updated question for details.

Comment: As Intel makes plain at their software download sites, the drivers they offer are not intended for end-users to install on their machines. Updated drivers MUST come from the computer/motherboard vendor, because the drivers from Intel will refuse to install!

Answer (score 0):

You can search Intels website for the appropriate drivers.  They have them all there.  However, I have seen laptop video drivers on the intel site tell you to use the laptop manufacturers website.  Intel probably doesn't support them any more.

Comment: You are correct that the Intel drivers do not work and ask you to go to HP. That problem is the reason I asked my question, I have clarified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this web site free service: [Ma-Config.Com Easily explore your PC](http://www.ma-config.com/en)

From this site you have to install a browser plugin and a software which allow to scan your PC and check for the most recent drivers from the manufacturer.

You have the choice to download and install the driver you want.

Comment: It just points me at the same Intel driver that gives me the error that I posted in the updated question. Also the tool from Ma-Config.com feels very unprofessional. There are multiple languages in the dialog boxes, it is very easy to detect what language windows is set to and display the appropriate message. It makes me worry when I see sloppy work there, where else is there sloppy work?

Comment: 1-Check the display options on that "sloppy" site: most recent, WHQL certified... 2- I give you the link for your language Sir.- Make a restore point, download the driver they give you, install it and check if the problem is solved. The other options for you are Intel web site or updating the driver with devmgmt.msc from Microsoft. :-)

Comment: 1- It is not the site that was sloppy, it was the executable that was downloaded to check the installed devices on the system, the language thing was one of many things that made me cringe as a software developer when I ran it. 2- the program told me to download the drivers I referenced in my original post... **which do not work** and tell you to go to the manufacturer's website.